# Angular Universal with REST API

Tags: angular, angular-universal

I'm pretty new to Angular Universal (to be precise, to universal web apps as well), and I'm kind of struggling with it. I have a working ng7 Universal code, with the initial page load rendered on the Node server, just like in the example app. My question is, what about the REST API calls that get fired in the browser? I know, once the application gets bootstrapped in the browser, it behaves just like a normal single page application - the browser will take care of the rest.

Is there any kind of method which makes it possible to either:

- prevent the browser firing the http client request and somehow redirect these to the node server

or

- every time the browser makes an http client request, the Node server should just re-render those parts of the DOM that the response might affect

I know this sounds fuzzy as hell, but my client has a problem with the "Network tab" in the browser - he doesn't want to see all the JSON responses there, due to the project's business logic - rather just make the Node render the DOM changes (which normally would be the browser's task). Is this even possible? I have several reasons not to do this way, but in the end, I have to say he is pretty much right: this isn't really server side rendering as soon as the initial page loads.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome @eyho.  Even though I'm coding in Angular, I'm having trouble understanding your question... can you possibly rework it to... really ask something specific?  "How do I do X"... and show code that you've tried that doesn't work?  It's hard for anyone to work with your question as it is.  Good luck!

Comment: I wrote a way to do this - https://dev.to/jdgamble555/angular-universal-rest-api-endpoints-23fj

Answer (score 0):

Just to clarify, the html corresponding to the initial route is generated dynamically with angular universal and returned to the client. The client angular app then bootstraps and replays the API requests and component creation.

To prevent these API requests from being replayed **on the initial page**, you can use the [TransferState](https://angular.io/api/platform-browser/TransferState) API. This will basically cache the JSON responses in the page's html. But this will only work for the initial route. Once you start navigating though your app, it will be business as usual and you'll have JSON data retrieved, visible in network tab.